# Dungeon Crawl - Map

Tags: python, dictionary, random, pygame

Alot of the tutorials on the web instruct me on how to create a randomly generated map with varying sized rooms etc. I dont want this, I want a Binding of Isaac style map where each room is the same size and is the only thing on the screen.

Therefore, Im trying to find a way to generate a map where a group of say 8-10 randomly selected rooms out of the room pool are picked and grouped together to create a map.

Ive tried doing this but havent managed to get very far. This is the code that I used to try and make things random

```
def main():

rooms = []

room = Room1()
rooms.append(room)

room = Room2()
rooms.append(room)

room = Room3()
rooms.append(room)

room = Room4()
rooms.append(room)

current_room_no = random.randint(0, 2)
current_room = rooms[current_room_no]




# Game Logic

player.move(current_room.wall_list)

if player.rect.x < -15:
    if current_room_no == 0:
        current_room_no = random.randint(0, 3)
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 790
    elif current_room_no == 3:
        current_room_no = random.randint(0, 3)
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 790
    elif current_room_no == 2:
        current_room_no = random.randint(0, 3)
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 790
    else:
        current_room_no = 0
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 790

if player.rect.x > 801:
    if current_room_no == 0:
        current_room_no = random.randint(0, 3)
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 0
    elif current_room_no == 1:
        current_room_no = random.randint(0, 3)
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 0
    elif current_room_no == 2:
        current_room_no = random.randint(0, 3)
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 0
    else:
        current_room_no = 0
        current_room = rooms[current_room_no]
        player.rect.x = 0
```

Let me know if any more code is needed!

Comment: It's not very clear from your code what _exactly_ you are trying to do, as you have excluded a lot of the code for your Room1 etc. functions. Also, generally StackOverflow is used if you have a specific problem, rather than just generally wondering where to go. It's a good idea to follow tutorials as closely as you can, ensuring that you understand everything, before trying your own projects. If you want to proceed—bearing in mind that it will be difficult to finish—just go ahead until you encounter a specific issue, which you can track down to a small part of your code, then ask about that.

Comment: No worries! ill be sure to do that from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope I can be of some use again in your game.
There is a specific function that takes a set of numbers and takes as many of them as desired. Say you wanted it to pick two numbers with six values. First you'd have to `import random` then you'd have to `random.sample(set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), 2)`. That would pick two values between one and six. You could just do the same in your game, switching the numbers for the variables. of each room. You could have them as numbers but the number `1` could be `Room1` and so on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh thankyou! Ill definitely mess around with that and see what I can pull off. Thanks for your help again!